# Where did this minority attack go wrong?

Tags: pawns, caro-kann

I have been playing the Caro-Kann recently and learnt that the exchange variation often involves a minority attack for black. I had never played a minority attack before, so I gave it a go. This was the game I played but I made a lot of inaccuracies according to the engine, and I don't like the position if not for the tactical shot at the end, as white has a passer and I'm not sure what I have, other than a nicely placed rook perhaps.

```
[Event "Rated Rapid game"]
[FEN ""]
[StartFlipped "1"]
[Date "2021.12.23"]
[WhiteElo "2069"]
[BlackElo "2019"]
[TimeControl "600+0"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[UTCDate "2021.12.23"]
[UTCTime "09:21:50"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[ECO "B13"]
[Opening "Caro-Kann Defense: Exchange Variation"]

1. e4 { [%clk 0:10:00] } 1... c6 { [%clk 0:10:00] } 2. d4 { [%clk 0:09:59] } 2... d5 { [%clk 0:09:58] } 3. exd5 { [%clk 0:09:59] } 3... cxd5 { [%clk 0:09:57] } 4. c3 { [%clk 0:09:59] } 4... Nc6 { [%clk 0:09:54] } 5. Bd3 { [%clk 0:09:57] } 5... Qc7 { [%clk 0:09:52] } 6. Nf3 { [%clk 0:09:56] } 6... Bg4 { [%clk 0:09:50] } 7. O-O { [%clk 0:09:55] } 7... e6 { [%clk 0:09:43] } 8. h3 { [%clk 0:09:49] } 8... Bh5 { [%clk 0:09:41] } 9. Re1 { [%clk 0:09:45] } 9... Bd6 { [%clk 0:09:28] } 10. Bg5 { [%clk 0:09:39] } 10... h6 { [%clk 0:09:24] } 11. Be3 { [%clk 0:09:35] } 11... Nf6 { [%clk 0:09:19] } 12. Nbd2 { [%clk 0:09:30] } 12... O-O { [%clk 0:09:09] } 13. Qb3 { [%clk 0:09:29] } 13... Na5 { [%clk 0:08:50] } 14. Qa4 { [%clk 0:09:25] } 14... a6 { [%clk 0:08:20] } 15. Rac1 { [%clk 0:09:13] } 15... b5 { [%clk 0:08:13] } 16. Qd1 { [%clk 0:09:09] } 16... Nc4 { [%clk 0:07:19] } 17. Nxc4 { [%clk 0:09:02] } 17... bxc4 { [%clk 0:07:17] } 18. Be2 { [%clk 0:09:01] } 18... Rab8 { [%clk 0:07:08] } 19. b3 { [%clk 0:08:50] } 19... cxb3 { [%clk 0:07:02] } 20. axb3 { [%clk 0:08:50] } 20... Ne4 { [%clk 0:06:48] } 21. c4 { [%clk 0:08:34] } 21... Qb7 { [%clk 0:05:59] } 22. c5 { [%clk 0:08:02] } 22... Bc7 { [%clk 0:05:40] } 23. g4 { [%clk 0:07:18] } 23... Bg6 { [%clk 0:05:11] } 24. Nd2 { [%clk 0:07:15] } 24... Nxd2 { [%clk 0:05:07] } 25. Qxd2 { [%clk 0:07:10] } 25... Qxb3 { [%clk 0:04:13] } 26. Bxa6 { [%clk 0:07:08] } 26... Ra8 { [%clk 0:04:05] } 27. Be2 { [%clk 0:07:01] } 27... Ra2 { [%clk 0:04:03] } 28. Qc3 { [%clk 0:06:47] } 28... Qxc3 { [%clk 0:03:45] } 29. Rxc3 { [%clk 0:06:45] } 29... Ba5 { [%clk 0:03:43] } 30. Rec1 { [%clk 0:04:51] } 30... Bxc3 { [%clk 0:03:24] } 31. Rxc3 { [%clk 0:04:51] } 31... Rxe2 { [%clk 0:03:23] }
```

13...Na4 I thought was good because it prepared jumping onto the outpost with tempo, strongly provoking recapture, leaving me with a half open file with my rook staring at a pawn that I was sure to eventually capture. But the engine marks this as the first of many mistakes.

From the little success I had I felt like I misunderstood what I am really trying to achieve here in this attack. Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question. It's a deep one that is not easily answered by turning on an engine.

The goal of the minority attack is to leave your opponent with attackable weaknesses. If you look at the pawn structure after 13. Qb3, what you are ideally hoping for is b5-b4-xc3, and then after White recaptures (bxc3) you play Rac8, Rc7, Rfc8, etc, and whomp the now-backwards pawn on c3. Alternatively, if White plays cxb4, then you can now target the newly-created weaknesses on b2 and d4. The former is on a half-open file, while the latter is now isolated.

There are however problems with this plan. Notably, White can play c4, which throws the entire plan out of the window. If you look at [examples](https://www.chess.com/terms/minority-attack-chess) of the minority attack, this square (c4) is usually cast-iron controlled before the attack begins. As it is, White is more ready to play c4 (opening lines for their major pieces and therefore developing queenside play) than you are to play a minority attack.

In any case your minority attack never really takes place because you played Nc4, changing the pawn structure away from one that's amendable to a minority attack. It's not that 16...Nc4 is a bad move - White's rather aimless drifting with the queen let you seize lots of queenside space. But after 16...Nc4 17. Nxc4, there is no more minority attack.

By the way, 13...Na5 doesn't actually threaten to jump onto an outpost, because even if you get in ...Nc4 (White currently has more attackers on that square than you have defenders), your knight can still be ejected with b3.

Comment: Also, note that the minority attack is nearly busted nowadays - White plays b4 and installs a knight on c5, making the c3 absolutely safe against rooks and leaving the Black pawn on b5 as a weakness. (This is to be taken with a grain of salt, consider a modern middlegame book for details.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann well that's depressing I only just found out about minority attacks haha. Unfortunately the middlegame books I have are Kmoch's 'Pawn Power in Chess' (not exactly modern) and Hellsten's 'Mastering Chess Strategy' which I feel like says weirdly little about minority attacks in the first place. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, no, I learnt from the classics :-) Here is another thread on the theme: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/books-about-minority-attack